# how to filter a dataframe based on List of id?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

my dataframe look like

```
     df.show()
     id |
     1  |
     2  |
     3  |
     .
     .
     .
     df.count()
     26137
     df.distinct().count()
     26137
```

I have a list

```
     lisst=List(4,75,30)
```

I want to get a dataframe without rows in lisst so I tried

```
     val df1=df.filter(!(col("id").isin(lisst:_*)))
```

when I want to count rows in df1 normaly i'll have 26134 but I have

```
     df1.count()
     25791
```

also I change lisst to

```
     lisst=List()
     df.filter(!(col("id").isin(lisst:_*)).count()
     25669
```

how can get a dataframe without id in a List.

Comment: My question different of this question I m asked to filter a datframe and get rows that not in List when I tried the method with "!" I get false result I think "!col("id").isin(lisst:_*)" work with regex I added a string to the list and it work for me for example if lisst=List("blabla",1,2,140)===> df.filter(!col("id").isin(lisst:_*)).count() give 26134.

Answer (score 2):

apparently, some of your ids are null. To get the full count, use:

```
 lisst=List()
 df.filter(!(col("id").isin(lisst:_*) or col("id").isNull).count()
```

Comment: does'nt work same give me 25560, df.filter(col("id").isNull).count() give 0